# C++: Getting HTTP Response Code

Tags: c++, http, response, wininet

I am trying to retrieve an HTTP response code from a URL in C++ using WININET.  Whenever I use the following code, it always returns 2 or 4, instead of 200 or 404, etc.  Please show me what I did wrong here:

```
HINTERNET hOpen;
HINTERNET hFile;
hOpen = InternetOpenA("MYAPP", INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT, NULL, NULL, 0);
char* url = "http://www.google.com/";
hFile = InternetOpenUrlA(hOpen, url, NULL, 0,INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD, 0);
char responseText[256]; // change to wchar_t for unicode
DWORD responseTextSize = sizeof(responseText);
if(!HttpQueryInfo(hFile,HTTP_QUERY_STATUS_CODE,&responseText,&responseTextSize,NULL)) {
    return -1.0;
}
cout << "Response: " << responseText << " ";
```

Comment: What if you explictly use `HttpQueryInfoA` ?